# gzip video file on Samsung S6 vs Sony Xperia

Tags: android, compression, gzip

I have a gzip compression applied to a video file.  On Samsung S6 the gzip compresses to byte size 2175949 from  original bytes.length of 2195647 of the video file.  The gzip compression almost has no effect.

However, when applying the gzip compression on a video file in Sony Xperia phone the compression reduces the file length to almost half of the file size like 1.3 megabytes from 2 mb.

Is there something about the video files produced on each device? Any suggestions is helpful.

thanks

Comment: Video formats can vary in size due to different encoding parameters. Each device may be using a different format or additional/different metadata, i.e. Samsung could be a well compressed vs less so on Sony. How are they created? are you accounting for content (static vs action)? Are they even the same format - i.e. pull each file and look at the media info metadata with a video player.

Comment: The video files are created in my CameraActivity by the user.  I will check on the metadata.